# Why can't SwiftUI's Image see the AppIcon file?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swiftui, assets

I noticed a weird quirk in SwiftUI.
If I try and get the app icon from the Assets folder (the icon exists) using this:

```
Image("AppIcon")
```

It doesn't work. No image displays. That being said literally every other image in the Assets folder works fine though using that same line of code, just not AppIcon.

If I use this:

```
Image(uiImage: (UIImage(named: "AppIcon"))! )
```

It works perfectly fine. The app icon shows.
Is there any reason why Image can't display the AppIcon asset?

Comment: I guess SwiftUI `Image` is just not designed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found clear documentation from Apple, but the "AppIcon" asset seems to often be blocked from the image name space.

The workaround is to create a separate Asset with a copy of the same file.

(When I'm prototyping new features, I like to reference the same image in an existing target.)

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you for the help!